# How to get the exe path using the runtime struct?

Tags: d, dmd

Under win7 the runtime (module) never gives me anything. I'd expect the first argument to always be the exe path but it's always empty.

Comment: Code? More context? Link to docs/libraries?

Comment: runtime.argc core.runtime after initiamize in a win form. just like in example winsamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the runtime returns empty values when a `WinMain` function is used (even after the call to `Runtime.initialize`).

Maybe Druntime should try and call the WinAPI functions to fill up the `rt_args`/`rt_cArgs` members if the compiler finds a `WinMain` function. Typically one would use [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391%28VS.85%29.aspx) to extract the arguments. A bug should probably be filed for this to [bugzilla](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/enter_bug.cgi?product=D).

As for the actual **path** of the current process, there is an open [pull request](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/pull/1224) that should make it into the next 2.064 release.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just to get the current path, `std.file.getcwd()` gives you the current directory.

Comment: running process path. not cwd

Comment: Using this leads to errors, I've recently seen  this on a software which was writing an ini in the wrong directory because it was launched from the console...(in the code the dev was assuming that cwd is the exe location)

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\work\so> dmd bbasile01.d

C:\work\so> bbasile01.exe
C:\work\so\bbasile01.exe

C:\work\so> type bbasile01.d
import std.stdio;

int main(string[] args) {
  writeln(args[0]);
  return 0;
} // main() function
```

Writing a cross-platform implementation of a function that gives running process path is not a trivial task... It has been discussed here on the StackOverflow in the past in hundreds of (not D related) threads.

Comment: I'm not kiding this code under Win 7 gives me nothing at all. I know that first arg is the exe path but the problem is: it's not the case from my side. I don't get why.

Comment: Normally I work on Linux, and args[0] gives me the executable name which is what I expected. I opened my other computer which has Windows 7 Ultimate on it. I installed dmd on it and compiled your code with test.d file name. When I executed, it displayed "test" on screen which is the name of test.exe already which is correct. I think you have a problem about your installation. (Win 7, 32-bit, DMD 2.063.2)

Comment: @BBasile : The example above is made on Windows 7. More precisely, VER gives `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]`, "dmd -v" gives `DMD32 D Compiler v2.063.2`. Try some other version of DMD...